# Automate calling of Visual Studio Code (extension) command (for example from powershell)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I would like to automate the following, presumably using powershell. The end goal is to automate generation of a **html** file out of a markdown file using the "Markdown PDF" extension without human interaction.

What I do manually:

1. open an existing markdown file (file.md)
2. Execute the command `">Markdown PDF: export(html)"`
3. close vs code

I've found that the command in question is called `"command": "extension.markdown-pdf.html",` (from the extension package.json file) but I haven't figured out how to interact with the running visual studio code instance or feed in a command do execute at startup.

Comment: There are command-line tools to convert markdown to PDF.  `pandoc` is the best, although it takes some work to configure, because it needs LaTeX.

Comment: fyi: the source code is at https://github.com/yzane/vscode-markdown-pdf/blob/master/extension.js

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "without human interaction"? you later say you want it done at startup? how else are you going to trigger the thing to happen without human interaction? you want it to happen periodically as soon as your machine boots?

Comment: A script to be started by a human is fine with me :D